# Generating SAS report with spaces in between for the same record/observations

Tags: sas, sas-macro

How can I generate this kind of report/table:

```
obs record_no task
1   rec_1     t1
              t2
              t3
2   rec_2     t1
              t2
              t3
3   rec_3     t1
              t2
              t3
```

data set 1 contains

```
obs record_no
1   rec_1
2   rec_2
3   rec_3
```

data set 2 contains

```
obs task
1   t1
2   t2
3   t3
```

I need all the task to be redundant for rec_1 to rec_3; also the blanks spaces just like in the above example.
How can I achieve the above report ?

@TOWHOSOVERITMAYCONCERN - 
for the negative marking, I am not asking for code from anyone just push me in right direction. Have nothing nice to say don't say it just scroll off!

Comment: PROC REPORT with the GROUP option on the variable.

Comment: This is not a valid SO question, you need to post what you've tried and what hasn't worked. A quick google search should put you on the right path quickly.

Comment: @Reeza I can achieve the above but only without the blank spaces, I need the blank spaces to be there instead of repeating the same data

Comment: Do you want a REPORT or a DATASET? If you want a dataset do you want it to have 9 observations or 3?  What did you try and how did it not meet your needs?

Comment: Like I mentioned, this isn't a valid SO question and, wait, I did point you in the correct direction. You still haven't posted anything you've tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my own solution to this is not that hard in fact
used the following ways -

- with Cartesian product I merged both sets in a one to one aspect.
- then by using reports I ordered the merged dataset (in my case there
  were 4 more variables to be ordered achieved it by ordering each one.
  )